# Prove that $U_{a+b}=U_aU_b+U_{a-1}U_{b-1}$ for $a\ge1$ and $b\ge1$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove that $U_{a+b}=U_aU_b+U_{a-1}U_{b-1}$ for $a\ge1$ and $b\ge1$, where $U_a$=$\sum_k {a-k\choose k}$.

Therefore $\sum_k {a+b-k\choose k}$=$\sum_k {a-k\choose k}$$\sum_k {b-k\choose k}$ + $\sum_k {a-k-1\choose k}$$\sum_k {b-k-1\choose k}$.

How can I modify the right hand side of the equation to get the left hand side?

Comment: Have you tried applying Pascal's Rule to the first pair of sums on the R.H.S.? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule

Comment: the title of the question is different with your last explanation, which one is your problem?( + or - ? )

Comment: Hint: the choice of the letter $U$ is not accidental - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html

Comment: @AlexR. For applying Pascal's Rule to the first pair of sums on the R.H.S where Pascal's Rule is ${n-1\choose k}+{n-1\choose k-1}={n\choose k}$ for $ 1\le k \le n$. Would you let ${n\choose k}={a-k\choose k}={a-k-1\choose k}+{a-k-1\choose k-1}$, getting $\sum_k {a+b-k\choose k}$=$(\sum_k {a-k-1\choose k}+{a-k-1\choose k-1})$$(\sum_k {b-k-1\choose k}+{b-k-1\choose k-1})$ + $\sum_k {a-k-1\choose k}$$\sum_k {b-k-1\choose k}$. If so I can see a link between the first pair of sums on the R.H.S and the second in the $\sum_k {a-k-1\choose k}$ and $\sum_k {b-k-1\choose k}$ terms. Is this correct?

Comment: @AlexR. I'm still stuck on this question, any small hints would be appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 2):

We derive a closed formula for a generalisation of $U_m$ which will then be used to prove the identity.

> The following is valid for $m\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\binom{m-k}{k}z^k
> =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{m+1}
> -\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{m+1}\right)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[t^m]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^m$ of a series. We start with the generating function
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-t-zt^2}
\end{align*}

> On the one hand it can be shown by *[partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Procedure)*
>   \begin{align*}
> [t^m]\frac{1}{1-t-zt^2}
> &=[t^m]\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}t\right)\left(1-\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}t\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{m+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{m+1}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   On the other hand we derive
>   \begin{align*}
> [t^m]\frac{1}{1-t-zt^2}&=[t^m]\frac{1}{1-t}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{zt^2}{1-t}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-t}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^j t^{2j}}{(1-t)^j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^j t^{2j}}{(1-t)^{j+1}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty t^{2j}\sum_{l=0}^\infty \binom{-j-1}{l}(-t)^lz^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty t^{2j}\sum_{l=0}^\infty \binom{l+j}{l}t^lz^j\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} [t^{n-2j}]\sum_{l=0}^\infty \binom{l+j}{l}t^lz^j\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n-j}{n-2j}z^j\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n-j}{j}z^j
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (3) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity  $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (5) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and use the rule $$[t^{p+q}]A(t)=[t^p]t^{-q}A(t)$$ We also restrict the upper limit of the sum since the exponent of $t^{n-2j}$ has to be non-negative.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $t^{n-2j}$.

> We obtain from (1) the following identity by setting $z=1$
>   \begin{align*}
> U_m=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\binom{m-k}{k}
> =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\cdot2^{m+1}}\left(\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{m+1}-\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{m+1}\right)
> \end{align*}

Next we calculate $U_aU_b$ and $U_{a-1}U_{b-1}$.

> \begin{align*}
> U_aU_b&=\frac{1}{5\cdot2^{a+b+2}}\left(\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b+2}
> -\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+1}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{b+1}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.-\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+1}\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{b+1}
> +\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b+2}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{5\cdot2^{a+b}}\left(
> \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b}
> +\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{b}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.+\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a}\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{b}
> +\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b}\right)\\
> \\
> U_{a-1}U_{b-1}&=\frac{1}{5\cdot2^{a+b}}\left(\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b}
> -\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{b}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.-\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a}\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{b}
> +\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b}\right)\\
> \end{align*}

It follows by collecting equal terms

> \begin{align*}
> U_aU_b+U_{a-1}U_{b-1}
> &=\frac{1}{5\cdot2^{a+b}}\left(
> \left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}+1\right)\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b}+0\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\left.+0+\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}+1\right)\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{5\cdot2^{a+b+1}}
> \left(\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b+1}+\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)^{a+b+1}\right)\\
> &=U_{a+b}
> \end{align*}
>   and  the claim follows.